# StatusBar transparente

Tags: android

Como implementar transparência na statusBar?

*API de compatibilidade minSdkVersion 16

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Só tem suporte da API 19+, veja esse [link](http://blog.raffaeu.com/archive/2015/04/11/android-and-the-transparent-status-bar.aspx) ou [esse](https://mindofaandroiddev.wordpress.com/2013/12/28/making-the-status-bar-and-navigation-bar-transparent-with-a-listview-on-android-4-4-kitkat/).

Answer (score 0):

Crie um estilo com a colorPrimaryDark com transparência

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
...
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.StatusBar.Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/actionBar</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#33000000</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

No AndroidManifest.xml associe o estilo a activity

```
<activity android:theme="@style/AppTheme.StatusBar.Transparent"
          android:name="TestActivity">
</activity>
```

No método onCreate da activity implemente o método statusBarTransparent

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setContentView(R.layout.test_activity);

  ...

  statusBarTransparent();
}     

private void statusBarTransparent()
{
   getWindow().getDecorView()
              .setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);

  DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

  int marginTop = (int) Math.ceil(25 * dm.density);

  View view = findViewById(R.id.frmClient);

  ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

  lp.setMargins(0,marginTop,0,0);
}
```

test_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mapBse"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frmClient"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/frame_square">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgMnu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_d"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgMnu"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:textColor="#999999"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:text="Pesquisar indicador"/>

        </RelativeLayout>


    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Cópia da tela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]